# Remove notification after clicking

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications

I want that the notification will be closed after the user is clicking on it. I saw that everybody saying to use flags, but I can't find the flags anywhere because I'm using NotificationCompat.Builder class and not Notification class. Someone have any idea how to make the notification remove by her self?
Here is my code when I'm setting the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Question")
            .setContentText("" + QuestionData.getAuthor().getUserName() + ": " + QuestionData.getQuestion() + "");

    Intent openHomePageActivity = new Intent("com.example.ihelp.HOMEPAGEACTIVITY");
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openHomePageActivity);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);       

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 346):

Easy, simply call this:

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Also, while it's not really necessary, if you really want to use `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`, just call this before you call `mNotificationManager.notify`:

```
mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: This is the best answer..the flag_auto_cancel wasn't working..you saved my day!

Comment: `getNotifications` is deprecated, use: `mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;` instead

Comment: mBuilder.build() is also deprecated

Comment: when I tap on notification, this setAutoCancel(true) works, indeed. BUT when I click on Action in the notification (call in my case), it DOES NOT WORK!

Comment: @Async- Could you provide more details? Maybe as a new question on SO?

Comment: Please see my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595594/notification-is-not-being-dismissed-android/37610495

Answer (score 19):

Try this....

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 ..........
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_notify_icon)
            .setContentTitle("New Question!")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentText("" + QuestionData.getAuthor().getUserName() + ": " + QuestionData.getQuestion() + "");
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    ..............        


mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: `.getNotification()` is deprecated now use  `.build()` instead like `mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

Answer (score 14):

Here is notification:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_calendar)
            .setContentTitle("My Firebase Push notification")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

the key behind cancellation on click is:

```
            .setAutoCancel(true)
```

i hope it resolves the matter.

Comment: I am displaying the notification on foreground to and i want to dismiss that notification when user tap `.setAutoCancel(true)` already use this , but not working for me for foreground notification.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a flag to your notification:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

This will dismiss it upon clicking.

Comment: Add it to the notification flag of your Notification object.

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, you can use:

```
mBuilder.build().flags.and(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)
```